# How to request API call with a static IP on GCP’s App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I have a backend API wrapper that makes calls to the clash Royale API for player data etc. The clash Royale API assigns a key for a specific IP, therefore I need a static IP in order to successfully make a call to the API. The server works perfectly fine on localhost with the key assigned to my local IP; However, when I uploaded the server to GCP’s App Engine it no longer has a static IP. I did setup a static outbound IP using serverless VPC Access with Cloud Router and Cloud NAT and I setup a static inbound IP using a loadbearer. I assigned the IP’s to the API key but it still is not letting me make the API call. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/austinstiefel/Clash-Royale-API-Server

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml configuration with egress config?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the app.yaml has the following:
`runtime: nodejs20
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/poetic-palace-390223/locations/us-central1/connectors/cr-proxy-connector
  egress_setting: all-traffic`

Comment: It should work if you set a Cloud NAT with your own reserved IPs. Recheck your configuration and be sure to use the correct VPC.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere is there a way I can verify that the static ip is working?

Comment: I use that to validate my configuration: https://www.ipify.org/. Perform a simple GET and put the result in the logs.

Comment: The schema is basic: You have App Engine that live in the Google VPC and not in your VPC. So,  you create a bridge, the serverless VPC connector, to connect App Engine to your VPC. Now, the traffic lands in your VPC. Then, on this VPC you want to control the outbound traffic. So you put a proxy, a Cloud NAT, that catch the outbound traffic and proxy it with the Cloud NAT configuration. If you keep the network traffic flow in mind, you have simply to put the correct component to answer your question. Hope it's clearer...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I attempted to use ipify, it works just fine in my local testing environment but throws an error when deployed to the app engine.
Here is the error: https://pastebin.com/WDy1aNMF

Comment: Did you have changed/updated firewall rules or Cloud Route in y our project/VPC?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
Here's the firewall rule I added: https://ibb.co/kMgF8fk
I followed through this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses
I also used this documentation as well: https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gce-example#create-firewall-rule
However, using "curl example.com" still does not work on my VM at the end after following all steps.

Comment: Did you update the routes?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I don’t think any of the guides told me to edit any routes…so I’m not sure.